# Is it possible to do a "snap-to" effect while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am setting up a website like this (vertical slideshow almost):

http://mikelegacywebdesign.com/scrollpage_test/index.html

The one thing I am looking to do that I can't figure out is how to make the scrolling SNAP to the point where the color change is while scrolling.

For example, when scrolling, you get to about 50-100 px near the top of the next color you are scrolling to, it would be nice if that would snap to that point, instead of just continuing to scroll, because it is hard to get that "frame" to perfectly align. It's dependent on the user to scroll the perfect amount so that they are viewing the full frame, and not pieces of the former or next frame in the sequence.

Anyone that knows if there is a jQuery plugin or something for this would be my hero.

Here is the ENTIRE page so far. It's simple coding to get the current effect:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Scrollpage Test</title>

<style type="text/css">

    html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; }
    .container { height: 400%; width: 100%; }
    .section { height: 35%; width: 100%; }

    #section1 { background-color: #1d9ad7; }
    #section2 { background-color: #c83e3d; }
    #section3 { background-color: #75b946; }
    #section4 { background-color: #f4be2f; }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="section" id="section1"></div>
    <div class="section" id="section2"></div>
    <div class="section" id="section3"></div>
    <div class="section" id="section4"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Haven't had a chance to review it yet, but I'm looking for the same thing and came across this http://benoit.pointet.info/stuff/jquery-scrollsnap-plugin/

Comment: You might want to take a look at [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's [possible](http://community.saucony.com/kinvara3/). Their code is quite awful though. While animating `scrollTop`, you'll want to make sure that additional user-input that normally leads to scrolling is ignored. Have a look at this [test-case](http://jsfiddle.net/rodneyrehm/aPvFL/) to get an idea about how to prevent a user from scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the desired effect using the

```
scroll() jumpScroll() scrollBy()
```

and a little bit of your own code.

For example,

```
function jumpScroll() {
    window.scroll(0,250);
}
```

Would scroll to that point on the page

Answer (score 0):

I was after the same thing so [asked a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051650/stellar-js-configuring-offsets-aligning-elements-for-a-vertical-scrolling-we) a few weeks ago. I found an addon called [stellar.js](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/) that had the functionality but the demo was in horizontal and I couldnt for the life of me change it to vertical. Anyways, someone posted a solution, which I edited for mousescroll instead of click: http://jsfiddle.net/djsbaker/dxzk4/

On a site note, I had issues with it being quite laggy with huge fixed background images. In fact very laggy, but I was using parallax which didn't mix well.